# Drawing a wave java

Tags: java, math, graphics, wave, trigonometry

I'm looking to draw a wave. I have this so far:

```
private void drawWave(int yPos, int xPos, int colour, int length, int amplitude, int alpha) {
    int pixelY, pixelX;

    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        pixelX = xPos + i;
        pixelY = (int) (yPos - Math.sin(Math.toRadians(i)) * amplitude);
        Rasterizer2D.drawAlphaPixel(colour, pixelY, 1, 1, alpha, pixelX);
    }
}
```

This draws a wave but I cannot specify a wavelength to use, wasn't so sure how I could do that. Thanks a lot everyone.

Answer (score 0):

To modify the wave length, you could use this formula

F (x) = a * sin ( (1/b)*x )

Where a is amplitude, b is wavelength.

Looking at your code, you have amplitude in there. You just need a new parameter to specify b.

Comment: Not quite.  `b` would be proportional to the frequency, not the wavelength.

Comment: pixelY = (int) (yPos - (amplitude * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(i)) * waveLength)); Changed to this, has not worked.

Comment: This is true. Fortunately, wavelength is inversely related to frequency, so I was close enough. I editted it.

Comment: @user1009569 you need to insert the wave length inside of the sin function but outside of the radians.Right now it is a*b*sin (x), and it needs to be a*sin (b*x).

Answer (score 0):

Add an argument like `float wavelength` and change

```
pixelY = (int) (yPos - Math.sin( 2.0 * Math.pi * Math.toRadians(i) / wavelength) * amplitude);
```

You have

```
y(i) = y0 - A sin(i)
```

My equation gives you

```
y = y0 - A sin (2 pi i / L)
```

where `L` is the wavelength.

Now, this still may not do what you want.  It depends on what you want `xPos` and `yPos` to represent.  Do you want `xPos` to give you a phase shift?  If so, then you need to include it in your expression for `pixelY`.

Comment: XPos is just where the wave starts. It doesn't work, both the wavelength and amplitude are acting as amplitude, sort of...

Comment: Sorry, a better explanation is, xPos and yPos are just coordinates on the screen for the position of the wave, for example if I had 10, 10 then the wave would start drawing at (10, 10) (x, y)